# How to get an "approximately proportional to" symbol

Tags: stacking-symbols

I've looked everywhere, and there does not seem to be a symbol for this, i.e. a `\propto` with a `\sim` underneath. I've googled ways of combining these two symbols but haven't found anything satisfactory. Anybody know a simple way of achieving this? `\stackrel` and `\utilde` look horrible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit

Comment: I don't think that `\undertilde{\propto}` is acceptable: the tilde is quite different from `\sim`.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this isn't in unicode (though i haven't checked), but if it's a "recognized" symbol, i can submit it for consideration.  for documentation, this needs a published reference, preferably one that shows the symbol in context, and even better if the surrounding text clearly indicates the meaning, for example where the author is stating the symbol definitions for the document.

Answer (score 42):

```
\newcommand{\approptoinn}[2]{\mathrel{\vcenter{
  \offinterlineskip\halign{\hfil$##$\cr
    #1\propto\cr\noalign{\kern2pt}#1\sim\cr\noalign{\kern-2pt}}}}}

\newcommand{\appropto}{\mathpalette\approptoinn\relax}
```

If you don't need the symbol also in subscripts or superscripts, then the simpler

```
\newcommand{\appropto}{\mathrel{\vcenter{
  \offinterlineskip\halign{\hfil$##$\cr
    \propto\cr\noalign{\kern2pt}\sim\cr\noalign{\kern-2pt}}}}}
```

will do.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

With this code the spacing looks quite acceptable

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\approxprop{%
  \def\p{%
    \setbox0=\vbox{\hbox{$\propto$}}%
    \ht0=0.6ex \box0 }%
  \def\s{%
    \vbox{\hbox{$\sim$}}%
  }%
  \mathrel{\raisebox{0.7ex}{%
      \mbox{$\underset{\s}{\p}$}%
    }}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
a \approxprop b
\]
\end{document}
```

All this box stuff doesn't really look nice and there are probably easier ways to do this. However the result looks ok, and you can tweek the vertical position and spacing to whatever you like.

[image: approxsymbol]

EDIT: According to the comments from egreg and barbara beeton I've improved the code. Now, what about that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\app#1#2{%
  \mathrel{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\sim$}%
    \setbox2=\hbox{%
      \rlap{\hbox{$#1\propto$}}%
      \lower1.1\ht0\box0%
    }%
    \raise0.25\ht2\box2%
  }%
}
\def\approxprop{\mathpalette\app\relax}

\begin{document}
\[a \approxprop b\] \centerline{$a \approxprop b$}
\[\sum_{a \approxprop b}\]
\[X_{Y_{a \approxprop b}}\]
\end{document}
```

The result looks like that

[image]

(so I think it looks now ok in all sizes)

Comment: This code has many redundancies: `\vbox{\hbox{...}}` can be reduced to `\hbox{...}` and the `\mbox` inside `\raisebox` is useless. Also defining each time `\s` and `\p` can be avoided by defining them (with different names) beforehand.

Comment: using `\hbox` or `\mbox`, the symbol size won't change if this happens to be used in a subscript or fraction (not that that's likely).  `\text` would allow the sizes to change according to the current environment.  the `\mathrel` is a good idea though as it "corrects" the vertical alignment of the composite symbol.

Comment: @egreg: You were right. The code was pretty ugly, just a quick hack to get the symbol right. I've updated it now, and if there's still anything to improve I'll gladly hear from you.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for the comment. The size of the symbol adapts now to the environment as it should.

Comment: Define `\app` with *two* arguments (`#2` won't be used) and say `\def\approxprop{\mathpalette\app\relax}`. Also `\kern-\wd0` can be saved by saying `\rlap{\copy0}` which wouldn't move the current point. Don't use `\box1` for local assignments; change all references to `\box1` to `\box2` and what you have now as `\box2` can become `\box0` if you use `\box` instead of `\copy` (the box is built before performing the assignment to the box register).

Comment: Great, thanks. There's always so much to learn about TeX. I didn't know ``\mathpalette`` (cute) and had completely forgotten about ``\rlap``. What about box1? Is it reserved for something? As boxes are local to a group I wouldn't expect any problem here...

Comment: Knuth advises to use odd numbered scratch registers (1, 3, 5, 7, 9) only for global assignments and even numbered ones (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, but also 255) only for local assignments. You find why in the TeXbook (pages 301 and 346) or in TeX by Topic (look for "save stack"). A last remark: `\hbox` in `\rlap` is redundant, as `\rlap` already does `\hbox`.

Answer (score 5):

Does `underset` look better?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\underset{\sim}{\propto} \qquad \stackrel{\propto}{\sim}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better `\overset` than `\stackrel`

Comment: I tried these, problem is the spacing between the symbols is too large and it won't be properly centered vertically.

Comment: @Seb I see. I'm afraid I'm not very good with fine tuning of such constructs, but there are others here who can probably help you.

Comment: in both cases, the two symbols are different sizes, so neither is really appropriate, regardless of spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Does such a symbol officially exist? What about slight variations like `\propto\!\!\sim`

[image: \propto!!\sim]

or `\sim\!\propto`

[image: \sim!\propto]